# Basic python program

Tags: python

I tried to complete the program but the answer is wrong, and I can't pinpoint what exactly.

QUESTION: Given the equations of two lines (y=mx+b), determine if the two lines are parallel, the same or intersect. Calculate and output the point of intersection.

My code:

```
equation_1 =raw_input("Please enter the equation of your 1st line(y=mx+b): ")
equation_2 =raw_input("Please enter the equation of your 2nd line(y=mx+b): ")

plus_1 = equation_1.find('+')
plus_2 = equation_2.find('+')

x_1 = equation_1.find('x')
x_2 = equation_2.find('x')

equalsign_1 = equation_1.find('=')
equalsign_2 = equation_2.find('=')

b1 = equation_1[x_1+1:]
b2 = equation_2[x_2+1:]

m1 = equation_1[equalsign_1+1:x_1]
m2 = equation_2[equalsign_2+1:x_2]

if m1==m2 and b1!=b2:
    print "Your equations are parallel. "

elif m1==m2 and b1==b2:
    print "Your equations are the same. "

else: 
    equation_intersect_y = float(b2)-float(b1)
    equation_intersect_x = float(m2)-float(m1) # equation_intersect_x = float(m1)-float(m2)

    poi_x = float(equation_intersect_y)/float(equation_intersect_x)
    poi_y = float(b1)*float(poi_x)+float(m1)`
```

Comment: Is this a homework problem? :D

Comment: you give us no information about what is wrong...

Comment: crayzeewulf-no im just learning how to program and this is driving me nuts

Comment: What input do you give to the program, what is the output and what output did you expect?

Comment: The answer that my program outputs is wrong. It will not give you the correct POI. I suspect something wrong with the calculations.

Comment: Yes, that much is clear. Can you give an example?

Comment: I input 2 equations in the form y=mx+b
its supposed to find the POI between the two lines if there is one

Comment: *sigh* "I input y=5x+7 and y=8x+1, and it gives the answer 5.7 even though it should be 2.1" <-- something like this, please

Comment: I input y=2x+3 and y=-0.5x+7
REAL POI= (1.6, 6.2)
MY PROGRAM= (-1.60,-0.20)

Comment: @BalkarnGill Glad to hear that you are taking the initiative to learn. I suggest that you create a function that takes m1, b1, m2, b2 as parameters and test it out with several values of these parameters (without having to input them from a prompt). Post the test cases and results here. If this function works then the problem is probably in the way you are parsing the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you used for computing `poi_x` is wrong. Also, the formula your code used for calculating `poi_y` has `m` and `b` interchanged. Here is a slightly modified code that ought to help:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
equation_1 ="y=2x+3"
equation_2 ="y=-0.5x+7"

plus_1 = equation_1.find('+')
plus_2 = equation_2.find('+')

x_1 = equation_1.find('x')
x_2 = equation_2.find('x')

equalsign_1 = equation_1.find('=')
equalsign_2 = equation_2.find('=')

b1 = float(equation_1[x_1+1:])
b2 = float(equation_2[x_2+1:])

m1 = float(equation_1[equalsign_1+1:x_1])
m2 = float(equation_2[equalsign_2+1:x_2])

print m1,b1,m2,b2

if m1==m2 and b1!=b2:
    print "Your equations are parallel. "

elif m1==m2 and b1==b2:
    print "Your equations are the same. "

else:
    equation_intersect_y = b2 - b1
    equation_intersect_x = m1 - m2

    poi_x = equation_intersect_y/equation_intersect_x
    poi_y = m1*poi_x+b1

    print poi_x, poi_y
```

The output is:

```
2.0 3.0 -0.5 7.0
1.6 6.2
```

And here is a slightly better code that reduces repetition:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
def parse_equation_string(eq_string):
    x_pos = eq_string.find('x')
    equal_pos = eq_string.find('=')

    b = float(eq_string[x_pos+1:])
    m = float(eq_string[equal_pos+1:x_pos])
    return m, b

def get_point_of_intersection(line1, line2):
    m1, b1 = line1
    m2, b2 = line2

    if m1==m2 and b1!=b2:
        return "The lines are parallel. "

    elif m1==m2 and b1==b2:
        return "The lines are the same. "

    else:
        equation_intersect_y = b2 - b1
        equation_intersect_x = m1 - m2

        poi_x = equation_intersect_y/equation_intersect_x
        poi_y = m1*poi_x+b1

        return poi_x, poi_y

equation_1 = "y=2x+3"
equation_2 = "y=-0.5x+7"

line_1 = parse_equation_string(equation_1)
line_2 = parse_equation_string(equation_2)

print line_1, line_2
print get_point_of_intersection(line_1, line_2)
```

The output is:

```
(2.0, 3.0) (-0.5, 7.0)
(1.6, 6.2)
```

Comment: Wow thank you!
But why is it outputting "2.0 3.0 -0.5 7.0"
What if I just want the POI? How would I do that?
Thanks again :)

Comment: Also what if the input is y=x and y=-x?
How would I make that work?

Comment: I think I will let you figure both of those out on your own. [Try stuff first](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) :D

Comment: Okay i took out the extra print command, which fixed my first question. :D Sorry it was a dumb question but im just getting started with programming.

Comment: But I cant seem to get the 2nd question down. What if the input is y=x and y=-x? I think I would use another if statement but how and where?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
b1 = equation_1[x_1+1:]
b2 = equation_2[x_2+1:]
```

Be

```
b1 = equation_1[plus_1+1:]
b2 = equation_2[plus_2+1:]
```

Or

```
b1 = equation_1[x_1+2:]
b2 = equation_2[x_2+2:]
```

Also I think

```
m1 = equation_1[equalsign_1+1:x_1]
m2 = equation_2[equalsign_2+1:x_2]
```

Should be

```
m1 = equation_1[equalsign_1+1:x_1-1]
m2 = equation_2[equalsign_2+1:x_2-1]
```

Comment: It still outputs the wrong answer.
y=2x+3 and y=-0.5x+7
POI supposed to be (1.6, 6.2)
My program:
Your equations intersect in Quadrant 3(-1.60,-0.20)

Comment: To fix the x-intersect you need a check that says if (equation_intersect_x < 0) equation_intersect_x = equation_intersect_x*-1.  Still looking at the y-intersect issue.  Edit: Actually that fixes the y-intersect as well.  That's your issue.

Comment: Yeah, Crayzeewulf's is a cleaner solution.  Flip the deltas.  The rest will work itself out.

Answer (score 0):

First couple of suggestions:

Print back the equation to the user before performing operations (before the first "if" statement):

```
print "Equation 1  y={}x+{}".format(m1, b1)
print "Equation 2  y={}x+{}".format(m2, b2)
```

re or the string functions split and strip may be easier than string indexing:

```
m1 = equation_1.split('=')[1].split('x')[0]
b1 = equation_1.split('=')[1].split('+')[1]
```

Give the program some simple test cases before harder ones:
    1: y=0x+-3
    2: y=1x+0
    intersects at X = 3

```
1: y=-1x+0
2: y=0x+3
intersects at  X = -3


1: y=2x+2
2: y=-2x+0
intersects at X = -0.5
```

Now all that's left is the algebra:

Do a hard case by hand first:

Assuming they are not parallel or the same:
    find the point where x1=x2 and y1=y2
Find X where both Ys are equal:   Therefore:
    (m1)*x1 + b1 = y1 = y2 = (m2)*x2 + b2
    rewriting to find X: (m1)*x1 + b1 = (m2)*x2 + b2
    But at the point of interest (X) x1 = x2
    rewriting: (m1 + m2)*X = b2 -b1
    rewriting: X = (b2 - b1) / (m1 + m2)

Now we can see that this doesn't match your equation_intersect x formula.